# What constitutes a "description of B" for probabilistic encryption as defined in Cryptology 6.3.4?

Tags: number-theory, trapdoor

On page 21 of the Rivest's [Cryptology](http://people.csail.mit.edu/rivest/pubs/Riv90a.pdf) chapter, he defines a trapdoor predicate as a boolean function for which it is easy to choose an `x` such that `B(x) = v`, but hard for an adversary to compute `B(x)` given `x`, without the trapdoor information.

He goes on to say that Alice's public key contains a **description of B**.

What exactly goes into this description, to enable the trapdoor predicate property, without giving away the secret key?

Comment: For his definition, what goes into that description is either a [circuit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_circuit), an algorithm in some model (such as [Turing machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_machine)s or [word RAM](http://opendatastructures.org/versions/edition-0.1e/ods-cpp/1_3_Model_Computation.html), or a [clocked](https://people.cs.umass.edu/~barring/cs401s11/exams/final.html) algorithm in some model that's not restricted to just yes/no answers). $\;\;$ It's better define those to consist of specific algorithms that take a key as input. $\;\;\;\;\;$